# add stock intro and outro to a set of .mp3's?

Tags: podcast

If I have a bunch of existing podcast mp3's, with no intro and outro, can I do something simple to add a stock intro and outro (supplied as .mp3's) to each podcast?

Comment: Interesting question. A semantic playlist might be a good idea for this sort of thing. You'd greatly reduce redundant data being stored/downloaded, and users would be able to skip the intro/outro if they wanted to.

Comment: Did Keith's great answer deliver what you were looking for?

Comment: http://lyncd.com/2009/02/how-to-merge-mp3-files/

Answer (score 1):

Try the open source [MP3Wrap](http://mp3wrap.sourceforge.net/). This works on either Linux or Windows platforms.

Here's the syntax on Windows for a single file:

```
mp3wrap updated01.mp3 intro.mp3 podcast01.mp3 outro.mp3
```

The following *should* work for all files starting with `podcast` in the current directory when entered from the command line:

```
for /f %a IN ('dir /b podcast*.mp3') do mp3wrap updated%a intro.mp3 %a outro.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

It would all depend on the customization of your player. In flash you could theoretically play an mp3 at the beginning and end.

I'm not sure if you develop in flash or not, but it should be relatively simple.

If you are using another player, you may want to look into creating 'playlists' for each mp3.

Hope it helps!